# PM2 monit vs PM2 logs

Tags: node.js, command-line, pm2

What's the difference between these commands? I couldn't find a clear explanation on which should be used at what scenarios.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/

Answer (score 9):

[`pm2 monit`](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/process-management/?utm_source=pm2&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=rebranding) is about process management:

> The local monitoring tool get you insight about CPU usage, memory
>   usage, loop delay or request/min for each process

[`pm2 logs`](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/process-management/?utm_source=pm2&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=rebranding) is about log management and shows you the saved logs of all apps or a specific app - you won't see any details about the current CPU usage, memory usage and so on.

In my understanding `pm2 monit` provides a ad hoc view about the current processes including their logs in real time, while `pm2 logs` provides a retrospective view through saved logs (though they are also available at realtime).